# how to get datetime value from field with java in lotus

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I use IBM notes and IBM Domino designer. I have a form with a date/time field. This field is called 'Orderdatum', from a java agent I call this field by eventually doing this:

```
orderDocument.getItemValueDateTimeArray("Orderdatum")
```

If it's filled in then it works, but if it's empty then I get this:

```
NotesException: Item value is not a date type
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.NgetItemValueDateTimeArray(Native Method)
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.getItemValueDateTimeArray(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.postOrder(Unknown Source)
    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Even if I do checks like:

```
if(orderDocument.getItemValueDateTimeArray("Orderdatum") != null){
if(!orderDocument.getItemValueDateTimeArray("Orderdatum").equals(null)){
```

I still get the error in my console, how to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
if(orderDocument.getItemValue("Orderdatum") != null){
```

Comment: Even safer:

if ( (orderDocument.hasItem("Orderdatum) ) &&   ( orderDocument.getItemValue("Orderdatum") != null) ) )

Comment: Thank you very much